# What is the Facebook mail address of an account that only have an ID?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-groups, facebook-timeline, facebook-messenger

How to precisely find the Facebook email address of the person that only have a Facebook number ID, that is a profile, for instance

```
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=606247083
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't find the real email address of the profile, until or unless profile owner haven't kept the profile visibility open to friends or you.

Comment: I would simply need to get the mailbox content of the account without the FB interface

Comment: This is right information, but this doesn't answer the question. This is not what OP is asking. @cutiehulk2329

Comment: Yeah I got it recently. Even I too waiting for someone to answer the thread. Why don't you try.